# MongoDB findOneAndUpdate duplicates documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, async-await

My object(document) in MongoDB looks like this

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("62dead1c5bcb14c13ab82c42"),
  artistName: 'Artist 1',
  artistSpotifyId: '6ckI88Ggj8DPe0TNAAVkj',
  connectedGroupId: '62de84faa65ba6e0552c8ce4',
  connectedGroupName: 'Group 1',
  createdBy: 'username1',
  createdAt: '2022-07-27T11:47:56',
  __v: 0
}
```

On client, I created a service for editing the object, purpose is for editing the group ID and group name only, I'm sending the ObjectId and group details within the content

```
const editArtistGroup = async (_id, connectedGroup) => {
  const content = { _id, connectedGroup }
  const response = await axios.put('http://localhost:3001/artists', content)
  return response
}
```

Server code: all received successfully, some parsing occurs and then I'm updating the existing object with new details.

```
router.put('/', async (req, res) => {
  const { _id, connectedGroup } = req.body
  const connectedGroupId = connectedGroup.split(',')[0]
  const connectedGroupName = connectedGroup.split(',')[1]
  const updatedArtist = await Artist.findByIdAndUpdate(
    { _id: _id },
    {
      $set: {
        connectedGroupId: connectedGroupId,
        connectedGroupName: connectedGroupName,
      },
    },
  )
  res.json(updatedArtist)
})
```

What happens, is that object with the aforementioned ID `62dead1c5bcb14c13ab82c42` is updated successfully, however, for some reason, the object is duplicated, new one is created, having the updated details and new object ID.
Any idea why the duplication occurs? I'm using the exact same code on a different project and it works just fine.

Comment: I've never ever used `findByIdAndUpdate`, but the usage you are doing seems somewhat wrong, as the documentation states _ findByIdAndUpdate(id, ...) is equivalent to findOneAndUpdate({ _id: id }, ...)._ So it looks like you should use `_id` instead of `{ _id: _id }`, not sure whether that's the issue. The documentation, though, does not mention anything about what happens if a document is not found, perhaps it is upserting? https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-findByIdAndUpdate

Comment: I changed `{ _id: _id }` to `_id` but it didn't help. In my case, documents is always found, so I guess the `upsert` is not suitable here.

Comment: Upserting is not suitable, my guess was that since the upsert behavior is similar to the one described. Can you ensure that the duplication is effectively happening from that code and not from something else? the best check you can do is count the documents before the findByIdAndUpdate and after, so that in case a new document is created the count is different. Otherwise, if the count is the same, the problem is likely somewhere else.

Comment: By default, `findByIdAndUpdate` updates the matching document _and_ returns the document _before_ the update.